# ¿Cómo extraer un parametro url con una expresión regular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
var texto= "//portal.sidiv.registrocivil.cl/docstatus?RUN=123456-4&type=CEDULA&serial=108538812&mrz=108538898884123132412311";
$("#probar").html(texto.match(/\docstatus?(.*?)\&type/)); 

<div id="probar"></div>
```

De el quiero extraer la palabra:

```
RUN=123456-4
```

pero no he obtenido resultado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para detectar con una regex, la idea es buscar primero `"RUN"` y despues, coger la cadena siguiente hasta el primer `"&"`

La regex seria `/RUN=[^&]+/`

Explicacion:

- `RUN=`  -> indica literalmente `"RUN="`
- `[^&]+` -> indica que coja cualquier cadena de texto consecutiva que no contenga el caracter `"&"`.

El resultado de `match(regex)` es un array con el *full match*  y los grupos de captura. Nosotros no hemos especificado ninguno así que accedemos al primer y único elemento con `[0]`

```js
var url = "//portal.sidiv.registrocivil.cl/docstatus?RUN=123456-4&type=CEDULA&serial=108538812&mrz=108538898884123132412311"

var regex = /RUN=[^&]+/

console.log(url.match(regex)[0])
```

---

Para hacer algo más general, podemos hacer una función `extraerParametro()` que como argumento reciba la url y el string del parámetro a buscar:

```js
var url = "//portal.sidiv.registrocivil.cl/docstatus?RUN=123456-4&type=CEDULA&serial=108538812&mrz=108538898884123132412311"

console.log(extraerParametro(url, "run"));

console.log(extraerParametro(url, "serial"));

function extraerParametro(url, param) {

  var regex = new RegExp(param + "=([^&]+)", "i")

  return url.match(regex)[1]

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Aunque la respuesta ya esta, dejo mi contributo.

otra opcion seria crear una funcion :

```
function tomarParametroUrl(nombre){
    nombre = nombre.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regexs = "[\\?&]" + nombre + "=([^&#]*])";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexs);
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if(results == null)
        return "";
    else
        return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " ");
}
```

ejemplo de utilizo :

```
var parametro = tomarParemetroUrl("RUN");
```

resultado : `123456-4`

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar el `indexOf` de `jquery` para ubicar las posiciones de donde empieza y termina tu palabra:

```
var texto= "//portal.sidiv.registrocivil.cl/docstatus?RUN=123456-4&type=CEDULA&serial=108538812&mrz=108538898884123132412311";

var sign = texto.indexOf("?") + 1;
var and = texto.indexOf("&type");
```

El signo "?" en una `url` siempre aparece solo una vez, por que sirve para indicar el inicio de los parámetros de la `url`, el + 1 lo agrego para que tome el texto que esta una letra después del `index`.

El "&type", es el `index` final del código que buscamos, así que obtenemos el `index` de ese texto.

```
$("#probar").html(texto.substring(sign,and));
```

Por ultimo hacemos un `substring` a texto, indicando las posiciones que queremos que tome.

Espero y sea lo que necesitas.

Saludos.

Comment: eso hice, pero una expresion regular es mas precisa